How to run Sidekiq dashboard behind AWS API Gateway?
We use AWS API Gateway in front of our application. We have an openapi.yml file that defines all our routes to our API. If we omit listing one of our endpoints in openapi.yml, our app never receives those hits. (ask me how I know...)
We run the sidekiq GUI dashboard locally in development, but now need to add access to it in production.
Is there a shortcut to allowing all the routes that Sidekiq needs in openapi.yml? I'm not super excited about sniffing out every path it needs and adding manually, and hoping they don't change much in the future.
As a wrinkle, for obscruity we are not deploying it in the default /sidekiq path. It is something like /admin/jobs

Adding this to openapi.yml did the trick:
  /jv_introspect/queues/{proxy+}:
    get:
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
        "401":
          description: Unauthorized
        5XX:
          description: Unexpected error.
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        httpMethod: GET
        payloadFormatVersion: 1.0
        connectionId: ${vpc_link_id}
        connectionType: "VPC_LINK"
        type: http_proxy
        uri: "${alb_uri}"
        tlsConfig:
          serverNameToVerify: ${tls_server_name}
    post:
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
        "401":
          description: Unauthorized
        5XX:
          description: Unexpected error.
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        httpMethod: POST
        payloadFormatVersion: 1.0
        connectionId: ${vpc_link_id}
        connectionType: "VPC_LINK"
        type: http_proxy
        uri: "${alb_uri}"
        tlsConfig:
          serverNameToVerify: ${tls_server_name} 

